# Several EventHandlers / delegate blocks - How to stop processing?

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have a conceptional question about event handling.

Let there be several anonymous delegate blocks assigned to one Event. Basically, onedelegate does a check and should eventually stop processing the latter blocks if the check failed.

I know it is possible to put everything into a single delegate block and return whenever  needed.

However, when the check is required on several objects, the code has to be on everyone of them.

```
object1.SomeEvent += delegate {
  // check something
  if (somethingHappened) {
    // STOP!
    return;
  }
  // do something for object1 (if nothing happened)
}

object2.SomeEvent += delegate {
  // check something
  if (somethingHappened) {
    // STOP!
    return;
  }
  // do something else for object2 (if nothing happened)
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this? If so, how to do it?

```
EventHandler checkSomething = delegate {
  if (somethingHappened) {
    // STOP!
    // What to do here?
    return; // This won't prevent the other event handlers from executing. :(
  }
};

object1.SomeEvent += checkSomething;
object1.SomeEvent += delegate {
  // do something for object1 (if nothing happened)
};

object2.SomeEvent += checkSomething;
object2.SomeEvent += delegate {
  // do something else for object2 (if nothing happened)
}
```

---

**EDIT:**
The actual scenario:

The objects are of type UIButton (MonoTouch/UIKit) and receive the event TouchUpInside whenever the user stops tapping them (within their frame).

There is an error condition that should prevent both buttons from doing what they usually do and instead display an UIAlertView alarming the user about the error condition.

Comment: That's really not how events are supposed to function. One subscriber can't (and should not be able/allowed) stop the propagation of the event to other subscribers. I think that's what you're attempting to do, correct? If you provide a bit more information on the object the raises the event and what kind of thing each subscriber would do or what condition would stop the propagation, people can provide a solution that works

Comment: Sure it can and should - see CancelEventArgs and their usage throughout the WinForms system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you own the classes of object1 and object1 you could go through the invocation-list of the event yourself (instead of simply calling the event).

But it would become really messy. Consider alternative designs, for instance splitting it into 2 events (1 to do the checking).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't own the classes. The objects are instances UIButton (MonoTouch/UIKit) and the event is TouchUpInside (basically triggered when the user stopped tapping the button).

Comment: You cam always solve a problem by adding another class. One that subscribes to the button event (1x) and exposes 2 events for your other code.

Comment: This would probably give good results but also produces too much overhead (my primary goal was to simplify my code)

Comment: @riha: there would not really be any runtime overhead, and simplification is not always less code.

Comment: True. I might have a go at it when time allows. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `CancelEventArgs` and set cancel to `true` if the following eventhandlers should stop processing.

```
EventHandler checkSomething = delegate {
  if (somethingHappened) {
    // STOP!
    e.Cancel = true;
    return; // This won't prevent the other event handlers from executing. :(
  }
};

object1.SomeEvent += checkSomething;
object1.SomeEvent += delegate {
  if(!e.Cancel) {
    // do something for object1 (if nothing happened)
  }
};

object2.SomeEvent += checkSomething;
object2.SomeEvent += delegate {
  if(!e.Cancel) {
    // do something else for object2 (if nothing happened)
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice approach, but the event needs to be of type CancelEventHandler for that to work, right? I don't own the class and thus cannot change the event to that type.

Comment: Ok, thats hard. Although not very nice, you could store the Cancel-Flag on any other class commonly seen by all event-subscribers...

Comment: This somewhat also relies on the event invocation order (which shall not be taken for granted AFAICT), so I'll rather try to not implement it that way

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, the best practice is this:

```
 EventHandler checkSomething = delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {


           if (somethingHappened) {
                //STOP
                return;
            }//end if

            UIButton theButton = (UIButton)sender;
            if (theButton.Title == "Button1") {
            //do something for Object1
            }//end if

            if (theButton.Title == "Button2") {
            //do something for Object 2
            }
};
```

Comment: Looks promising. Is Object1 the class or an instance in that context? It looks like a class name to me. Since both objects are of the same class, would that still work?

Comment: First, let me know, is it your custom class?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Hmm, relying on the button titles feels like a last resort to me. Also, it probably doesn't scale well when there are lots of buttons. And what happens if button titles change by chance?

Comment: I just wrote this as an example. You can try the Tag property of UIButton.